# Wordpress: query_posts in a page that gets loaded into a div after the page is loaded

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I just got jQuery to be able to load a page into a body div.

Now I'm trying to get wordpress functionality into various pages that I can then load into that body div.

Everything loads and I know the right pages are being accessed but I've run into a very unexpected problem.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_head() in /home/nighthav/public_html/GENOMESTUDIOS.CA/wp-content/themes/GenomeStudios2013/news.php on line 2

I realize now that because the page is separate from the main site when it loads that it doesn't have any access to anything.

The page that needs to load is super simple:

```
This is a body blah blah
                    <?php wp_head();
                    global $query_string;
                    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
                    query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=1&order=ASC&cat=2');?>
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                            <h1>Title: <?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                                Body: <?php the_content(); ?>

                                Time: <?php the_time(); ?>

                <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Is there a way to regain the connection to my WP functions? Everything is in the same location.

I haven't used Wordpress very much and am out of practice so please make it as clear as you can.

---

Added:
If I remove the header call I get this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function query_posts() in /home/nighthav/public_html/GENOMESTUDIOS.CA/wp-content/themes/GenomeStudios2013/news.php on line 5

I have no connection to the Wordpress system from this page I'm trying to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the following code at the start of your file(before calling wordpress functions):

```
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
```

You adjust the `../` to match the `wp-blog-header.php` file of your wordpress installation(found in the top level folder).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `wp_head();` with `get_header();` or if you don't need the header there, just erase it.